# Build cask formula from source

Tags: homebrew

Is it possible to build cask formula from source instead of installing the corresponding pre-built `app`-file?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Homebrew-cask is for binary distribution.
Downloading binary and place appropriately is all what Homebrew-cask does.

If you look in a cask (package installation script), you'll notice there's no url for source file (.tar.gz) but only for binary file (.dmg, .zip, etc.).

Comment: @patrix Can the post notice be removed?